# iOS-App crashes for no reason when doing image processing a second time

Tags: image, cocoa, crash, touch

I'm really confused here. I am doing some image processing in Cocoa Touch and everything works well. My App uses about 120MB of memory, which is fine, and there are no leaks at all, which I checked using Instruments. However when I run the routine a second time with a completely new instance of my image processing class (after deleting the first of course) the app crashes on my iPhone 4. It still works fine on my iPad 3. Whenever I call "CGContextDrawImage()" is crashes. Obviously there is no exception thrown or anything the like. I really don't know why this is, since there should be enough memory available. Running it in Instruments on my iPad 3 shows that the never uses more than 120MB of memory.

Please find the code which causes the crash below. Again, it only crashes when doing this a second time and only on my iPhone 4.

```
CGImageRef imageref = [image1 CGImage];    
uint8_t *inBitmap1 = (uint8_t *) malloc(vectorsizeI);
CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate(inBitmap1, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRowI, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
CGContextDrawImage(context1, CGRectMake(xOffset1, yOffset1, imwidth, imheight), imageref);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's obvioulsy not enough memory. Maybe there is on iPad but there isn't on the iPhone. Keep in mind that the OS reserves only a small part of the physically available RAM (0.5 or 1 GB) for your app, and if it exceeds that limit, the system terminates the seemingly harmful process. Try to reduce your app's memory fingerprint somehow, 120 MB is not "fine".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is 120 MB too much? If I'm doing image processing on a 5MB image and I need it to be float values, then one image alone takes up 80MB of space. Also why shouldn't I take advantage of the available memory. I have used up to 270MB of memory before on my iPhone 4 without problems.

Comment: @user1592187 that's a wrong question :) Why should you not eat up all the memory? Because you should always minimize memory usage. I know there's more RAM but the OS and other apps also need some. Your device will run smoother with less memory used.

Comment: Ok, I will definitely consider that. What I'm wondering about now is why it works the first time but not the second time.

Comment: @user1592187 you may be the victim of caching. Maybe CoreGraphics is lazy and doesn't "unnecessarily" deallocate some memory which is always used, and the BOOM that was the amount of RAM that crashed your app.

Comment: Btw does it still crash on 2nd try using smaller images (i. e. < 100kB)? If so, you might be corrupting memory.

Comment: Using smaller images the app doesn't crash. Problem is, this isn't going to work for me since I need to process full resolution pictures. Is there any reasonable way to deal with this or to get information about how much memory I can use and how much memory Core Graphics needs?

Comment: I wanted to let you know that I have solved the problem. I was displaying four 5MP-Photos in UIImageViews which took up 80MB of memory. Apparently iOS doesn't count this as memory that the application uses so I wasn't able to see this using Allocations. The Memory Monitor instrument did show the entire memory usage so I would recommend using this together with Allocations. I solved the problem by releasing the images first, before doing a second computation. On iPhone 4 I am now able to use up to ±300MB of memory. Of course I will optimize my calculations to use as little memory as possible.

Comment: @user1592187 I'm glad you could finally solve it. (Please accept my answer if it was helpful, thanks!)